# How to keep hold of data on a Node.js server in case of error?

Tags: node.js

I'm working with Node.js on a serious project for the first time, building a multiplayer card game. I'm using socket.io for websockets. The Node.js server should run 24/7 once the game is live.

Currently, I have a few issues I need to iron out. For clarity, I will split them into two sub-questions below.

First, every time there's an error the whole server crashes. I will try to iron out all bugs before going live of course, but it would still be nice if we could avoid killing the whole server process when one card game's data is corrupted. For example, if I refer to a non-existing element of an object, of course Node throws an error. That's fine, but is there a way to prevent such occurrences from crashing the server (besides making sure that this type of thing doesn't happen in the first place)?

Second, game states are stored on the server during gameplay. So, if there are 3 games in progress, there will be `states[1]`, `states[2]` and `states[3]` on the Node server. When the server crashes, I'd like to somehow keep hold of this data so the server could be restarted immediately and the data restored. I think sessions on the Node server are not an option because they will (presumably) die with the server, no? Storing everything to MySQL upon every game action seems like a huge waste of resources (but correct me if I'm wrong).

This all comes down to: how can I make sure the server can function autonomously through any potential problems without crashing and, if it has to crash, how can I make sure it doesn't take all ongoing games with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If bad state data is causing your app to crash, wouldn't reloading it after restart just cause another crash?

You should always validate that incoming data is completely valid before storing it, whether in-memory or in a database.

Whenever accessing a property of an object that may not exist, always check for that object's existence.

```
if (state[n].obj && state[n].obj.prop == val) ...
```

As far as storing your data out-of-process, your app sounds like a good candidate for a simple key-value store like Redis.  If you store all your state data in Redis, it will survive node restarts, and performance will still be similar to in-proc memory.  It also gives you the benefit of being able to scale beyond a single node process to handle heavy load.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into Redis. As for a reload causing another crash, how does Redis help in that regard? Can I have it remember what caused the crash?

Comment: It doesn't help, and that's my point: you need to fix the cause of the crash.  Persisting bad data outside of the node process is only going to make the situation worse.